# How to migrate the app.js configuration of this Vue 2 app for Vue 3

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite

I'm attempting to upgrade a Laravel/Inertia/Vue application. I've successfully upgraded to the latest version of Laravel, but I'm struggling with the Vue 2 to Vue 3 migration as none of the examples share all the features of the project (which I did not develop originally) I'm updating.

The original app.js file (Vue 2) looked like this:

```
import { App, plugin as Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue";
import i18next from "i18next";
import PortalVue from "portal-vue";
import Vue from "vue";
import VueCompositionAPI from "@vue/composition-api";
import VueMeta from "vue-meta";

// es version is needed specifically as there is no es5 version of Ziggy. This means we need to run
// it through Babel, which breaks the magic pairing of module.exports and import for some reason.
import route from "ziggy-js/dist/index.es";

Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI);
Vue.use(VueMeta);
Vue.use(Inertia);
Vue.use(PortalVue);

Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    /**
     * @param {string} name
     * @param {string|object} [params]
     * @param {bool} [absolute]
     * @param {object} [config]
     * @returns {any}
     */
    $route: (name, params, absolute, config = window.Ziggy) => route(name, params, absolute, config),
  },
});

import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
};

InertiaProgress.init();

// When more languages are added, this can be replaced by "window.lng" set by the server.
const lng = "en";

i18next.init({ lng }).then(() => {
  Vue.prototype.$i18next = i18next;

  const el = document.getElementById("app");

  new Vue({
    render: (h) =>
      h(App, {
        props: {
          initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
          resolveComponent: async (name) => {
            // We should exclude any component in a "Partials" directory, as these are
            // imported directly by the consuming component (and so shouldn't be compiled
            // as a standalone module.)
            const { default: component } = await import(/* webpackExclude: /Partials/ */ `./Pages/${name}.vue`);

            component.layout = component.layout === undefined ? AppLayout : component.layout;

            // If the component specifies language files, fetch them and register them with i18next.
            if (component.i18n) {
              (await Promise.all(component.i18n.map((file) => import(`@/lang/${lng}/${file}.json`)))).forEach(
                (bundle, index) => {
                  i18next.addResourceBundle(lng, "translation", {
                    [component.i18n[index]]: bundle.default,
                  });
                }
              );
            }

            return component;
          },
        },
      }),
  }).$mount(el);
});
```

I've converted the pre-existing laravel-mix build processes to use vite and followed the migration documentation for Vue 3 as far as I can. The key part that's not working is the  `resolveComponent` prop. I will include the rest of the file for the sake of completeness but I'm pretty certain it's just that bit that's the problem because if I change it to

```
    resolve: name => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
```

then the app renders albeit missing the site header which is contained in the AppLayout component.

Because I need to reintroduce that AppLayout layout to the component, I modified it so it looks like this:

```
//import { App, plugin as Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { InertiaProgress} from "@inertiajs/progress";
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue";
import i18next from "i18next";
import I18NextVue from "i18next-vue";
import PortalVue from "portal-vue";
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { resolvePageComponent } from "laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers";
//import VueCompositionAPI from "@vue/composition-api";
import VueMeta from "vue-meta";


// es version is needed specifically as there is no es5 version of Ziggy. This means we need to run
// it through Babel, which breaks the magic pairing of module.exports and import for some reason.
import route from "ziggy-js/dist/index.es";


import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
};

// When more languages are added, this can be replaced by "window.lng" set by the server.
const lng = "en";

i18next.init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: lng,
    resources: {
        en: {
            translation: {
                // tbc
            }
        }
    }
})

createInertiaApp({
    progress: {
        color: '#29d'
    },
    resolve: name => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')).then(function(module){
        const { default: component } = module;
        component.layout = component.layout === undefined ? AppLayout : component.layout;
        if (component.i18n) {
            (Promise.all(component.i18n.map((file) => import(`@/lang/${lng}/${file}.json`)))).forEach(
                (bundle, index) => {
                    i18next.addResourceBundle(lng, "translation", {
                        [component.i18n[index]]: bundle.default,
                    });
                }
            );
        }
        return component;
    }),

    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }){
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(PortalVue)
            .use(VueMeta)
            .use(I18NextVue, { i18next })
            .mixin({
                methods: {
                    /**
                     * @param {string} name
                     * @param {string|object} [params]
                     * @param {bool} [absolute]
                     * @param {object} [config]
                     * @returns {any}
                     */
                    $route: (name, params, absolute, config = window.Ziggy) => route(name, params, absolute, config),
                },
            })
            .mount(el);
    }
}).then(() => {
    InertiaProgress.init({});
});
```

the key difference now I suppose is that it's returning a component instead of a promise but I'm not sure how to fix it. Vue 2 migration docs just leave it at the simple version but I need it to apply the .layout property to the component and have that i18n translation stuff that was already in there.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I don't think there was a whole lot wrong with the resolve method I came up with. I added async await whether it was necessary or not. End result is this

```
    resolve: async name => await resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')).then(function(module){
        const { default: component } = module;
        component.layout = component.layout === undefined ? AppLayout : component.layout;
        if (component.i18n) {
            (Promise.all(component.i18n.map((file) => import(`@/lang/${lng}/${file}.json`)))).forEach(
                (bundle, index) => {
                    i18next.addResourceBundle(lng, "translation", {
                        [component.i18n[index]]: bundle.default,
                    });
                }
            );
        }
        return module;
    }),
```

The reason why it wasn't working is because of some other issues within the AppLayout component, or strictly speaking with one of the sub-sub-sub-components used in AppLayout. I'm currently stuck on those problems and trying to understand why none of the inertia links are working but this is not the right place for those details.